# Alarm not working with calendar time?

Tags: android

I am making an alarm application. It's working with some hardcoded values like

```
 calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND,30);
```

after 30 second alarm is firing but it's not working with

```
            cal.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.PM);
            cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,8);
            cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,2011);
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,4);
            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,5);
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,30);
```

Here is my whole code:

........Activity class..................

```
public class SampleAlarm1Activity extends Activity {
    public Context context;
    private boolean alarmstarted=true;
    Button setalarm;
    Button start;
    Button cancel;
    Edit Text year;
    EditText month;
    EditText date;
    EditText hour;
    EditText minute;
    Intent i;
    PendingIntent pi;
    AlarmManager am;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        context=getApplicationContext();
        setalarm=(Button)findViewById(R.id.setalarm);
        start=(Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
        cancel=(Button)findViewById(R.id.cancelalarm);
        month=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.month);
        date=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.date);
        hour=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.hour);
        minute=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.minute);
        setalarm.setOnClickListener(setalarmListener);
        start.setOnClickListener(startalarmListener);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(cancelalarm);
        start.setVisibility(android.view.View.INVISIBLE);
        month.setVisibility(android.view.View.INVISIBLE);
        date.setVisibility(android.view.View.INVISIBLE);
        hour.setVisibility(android.view.View.INVISIBLE);
        minute.setVisibility(android.view.View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    private OnClickListener setalarmListener=new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {   
            month.setVisibility(android.view.View.VISIBLE);
            date.setVisibility(android.view.View.VISIBLE);
            hour.setVisibility(android.view.View.VISIBLE);
            minute.setVisibility(android.view.View.VISIBLE);
            start.setVisibility(android.view.View.VISIBLE);
        }
    };
    private OnClickListener startalarmListener=new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int  mon = 0,dat = 0,hr = 0,min = 0;
            try{
                String  mon2=month.getText().toString();
                System.out.println("month string entered::::::::::"+mon2);
                mon=Integer.parseInt(mon2);
                System.out.println("month int valuereturn entered::::::::::"+mon);
                String  dat2=date.getText().toString();
                dat=Integer.parseInt(dat2);
                System.out.println("date entered::::::::::"+dat);
                String  hr2=hour.getText().toString();
                hr=Integer.parseInt(hr2);  
                System.out.println("hour  entered::::::::::"+hr);
                String  min2=minute.getText().toString();
                min=Integer.parseInt(min2); 
                System.out.println("minute  entered::::::::::"+min);
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException exc){
                System.out.println("exceptin is :"+exc);
            }
            Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            cal.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.PM);
            cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,mon);
            System.out.println("month string entered::::::::::"+mon);
            cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,2011);
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,dat);
            System.out.println("date  string entered::::::::::"+dat);
            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hr);
            System.out.println("hour   entered::::::::::"+hr);
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,min);
            System.out.println("minute  entered::::::::::"+min);
            i = new Intent(SampleAlarm1Activity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
            pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(SampleAlarm1Activity.this, 0, i, 0);
            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,cal.getTimeInMillis(),pi);
            System.out.println("alarm on in activity ");
            Toast.makeText(context, "alarm on  activity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
    private OnClickListener cancelalarm=new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(alarmstarted)
                try{
                    am.cancel(pi);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println("alarm not started"+e);
                }
                System.out.println("alarm cancel ");
                Toast.makeText(context, "alarm cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
}
```

broadcast receiver code....in same package ...........................................

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        System.out.println("alarm start");
        Toast.makeText(context, "alarm is working",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Manifest file..................................

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.android.SampleAlarm"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ALARM"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME_ZONE"></uses-permission>
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".SampleAlarm1Activity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"></receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had make the same application but I had select the time from Time Picker but you can put your own time. Here I post my sample application classes. It may be help you..

SampleReminderActivity.java

```
package com.reminder;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class SampleReminderActivity extends Activity {
    private Button btn = null;
    private AlarmManager alarmManager = null;
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    private Calendar calDay = Calendar.getInstance();
    private Calendar dateStart = Calendar.getInstance();

    static final int DIALOG_TIME = 0;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClick);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {                                   
                showDialog(DIALOG_TIME);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        Dialog dialog = null;
        switch(id){
        case DIALOG_TIME:
            dialog = new TimePickerDialog(this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                    c.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
//                    c.clear();

                    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, hourOfDay);
                    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

                    Log.d("SampleRemainder", "Before Intent");
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SampleRemainderActivity.this,AlarmReceiver.class);
//                    startActivity(intent);
                    Log.d("SampleRemainder", "After Intent");

                    Log.d("SampleRemainder", "Before PendingIntent");
                    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(SampleRemainderActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
                    Log.d("SampleRemainder", "After PendingIntent");

                    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), pi);

                    Toast.makeText(SampleRemainderActivity.this, "Alarm has been set..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            },cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE),false);

            Log.d("SampleRemainder", "get cal Hour **" + cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
            Log.d("SampleRemainder", "get cal Minute **" + cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));



            break;
        }
        return dialog;
    }
}
```

AlarmReceiver.java

```
package com.reminder;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        Log.d("AlarmReceiver","in AlarmReceiver"+ context.toString());

        Intent i = new Intent(context, AlarmActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

AlarmActivity.java

```
package com.reminder;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;


public class AlarmActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        Log.d("AlarmActivity","in AlarmActivity");

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        new AlertDialog.Builder(AlarmActivity.this).setTitle("Task").setMessage("Time to wake up").setPositiveButton("ok", new OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                AlarmActivity.this.finish();
            }
        }).create().show();
    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnClick"  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Click"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.reminder"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".SampleReminderActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".AlarmActivity"></activity>
        <receiver android:name="com.reminder.AlarmReceiver" android:process=":remote"></receiver>



    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>


</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi friend my problem is solved.

Note: use

```
     cal.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.AM or PM);
```

and      `cal.set(Calendar.HOUR,hour);`   for 12 hour format.

otherwise use  only `cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour)` for 24 hour format.

Other important thing i was doing mistake.

```
 cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
```

I was using 8 for august but it should be 7.
Actualy For January constant value is 0.

Thanks for your attention.